SecurityError: The operation is insecure on iOS in Next.js Project
I'm encountering a persistent SecurityError: The operation is insecure. issue in my Next.js project, but only on iOS devices. I've reviewed several related posts that suggest it could be a Firefox-specific issue, but in my case, the error occurs across all browsers on iOS.
Here is the log from Sentry:
column: 62797,
line: 63,
message: The operation is insecure.,
name: SecurityError,
sourceURL: https://website.com/_next/static/chunks/pages/_app-a65ffa319da93f05.js,
stack: 
get@https://website.com/_next/static/chunks/pages/_app-a65ffa319da93f05.js:63:62797
@https://website.com/_next/static/chunks/186-8e5aafdd07cb4743.js:1:1139
uI@https://website.com/_next/static/chunks/framework-42653e2defb541a0.js:9:84057
oU@https://website.com/_next/static/chunks/framework-42653e2defb541a0.js:9:113104
oC@https://website.com/_next/static/chunks/framework-42653e2defb541a0.js:9:95923
r8@https://website.com/_next/static/chunks/framework-42653e2defb541a0.js:9:44814
@https://website.com/_next/static/chunks/framework-42653e2defb541a0.js:9:111550
oI@https://website.com/_next/static/chunks/framework-42653e2defb541a0.js:9:111554
oS@https://website.com/_next/static/chunks/framework-42653e2defb541a0.js:9:94926
E@https://website.com/_next/static/chunks/framework-42653e2defb541a0.js:33:1365
T@https://website.com/_next/static/chunks/framework-42653e2defb541a0.js:33:1895

Key points:

The error is specific to iOS devices and occurs in any browser.
I do not have router.replace inside any useEffect.
I cannot reproduce the error on Vercel or locally; it only appears in Sentry logs.

Any insights or suggestions on what might be causing this issue would be greatly appreciated. Has anyone else faced a similar problem or have any ideas on how to debug this further?
Thank you!

At the first, you must know which part of your code encounters this issue. I guess you should delete some part of your code and then try to re-deploy it and find the exact place.

Not that easy as this is a big code and I can not lose users if I remove parts of the website

Create a [mcve] and post it. We don't want your production code.

I am unable to reproduce the bug in local or pre-production. I tried to do many test with the same devices and browser I can see in the logs clearing the cache but everything works well

Looks like it's specific to your production environment. You have to debug and analyze it, before others can help you.

@Ajouve, re-producing an error or issue, is the main part of debugging. You have to reproduce it somewhere to fix it. There's no other way.

have you check what is on _app-a65ffa319da93f05.js on the line 63:62797? You can download the file, then open it with VSCode and then Go > Go to line/column and paste that to check what is

Does the error occur on every iOs device or just specific ones? The error message normally occurs, when trying to use localStorage or sesionStorage on devices where users have limited access to it.
